# How to prevent overlapping divs with the first div using position: absolute?

Tags: html, css

I am running into an issue with overlapping divs. I have a page that is pretty simple:

```
<div class="scorecard-box">
<form>
<input>
</form>
</div>
  
 <div class="scorecard-table">
 <table>
 </table>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
  .scorecard-table {
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    top: 50%;
    position: relative;
   }

  .scorecard-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 40px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
   border-radius: 10px;
 }
```

There is obviously more to it but that is basically all there is, just a form with some inputs and a button, and below is a dynamic table that creates x amount of rows depending on the input selected in the form.

My problem is the 2nd div which contains the table is overlapping the first div when it should be underneath it.
[image: photo]

I have tried changing the position atribute of each div, but if anything it ruins the positioning of the first div.

Answer (score 1):

Theres something called "z-index" its a css attribute. It basically sets a z coordinate or a depth. Higher z-index number == in the front. So set the z-index of the one behind to 1 and the other to 10 or something.

```css
.un div, .do div{
  height:40px;
  width:40px;
  background:black;
  position:absolute;
}


.un div:first-child{
  top:30px;
  background:yellow;
  left:30px;
  z-index:2;
}

.un div:last-child{
  background:green;
  z-index:1;
}


.do div:first-child{
  top:30px;
  background:red;
  left:120px;
  z-index:1
}

.do div:last-child{
  background:blue;
  left:100px;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="un">
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
<div class="do">
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this helped in way although it still isnt perfect, but at least now the top margin % does make a change and it is below the first div.

Comment: Tip: when you want 50% of the screen, try use top:50vh